# gulp browser-sync не открывает браузер

Tags: javascript, gulp, browsersync

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста. Ввожу

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync({
server: {
  baseDir: "./"
},
notify: false,
});
});
```

код примерно вот так, в консоли пишет could not open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a hesdless environment you might want to set the open option to false)

Comment: В этом таске все правильно. В каком-то другом месте gulp-файла ошибка.

Comment: не может быть, так как я уже оставила в файле gulpfile.js только одну эту функцию - та же ошибка. Может ли это быть оттого, что у меня Виндовс7? Или нужно искать в каком-то другом файле?

Comment: вот полностью gulpfile.js

Comment: var gulp = require('gulp'),    
 browserSync = require('browser-sync');
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync({
server: {
  baseDir: "./"
},
notify: false,
});
});